# Python pygame error using font: no such file or directory

Tags: python, fonts, pygame

i have a python pygame program that simulates a racecar, driving and dodging blocks, this program worked 100% until i tried it today, now it gives me a error, the error is:

```
    Warning (from warnings module):
      File "/home/vandeventer/Documents/Pieter/pygame.resies.py", line 50
        largeText = pygame.font.Font(None,75)
    RuntimeWarning: use font: libSDL_ttf-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    (ImportError: libSDL_ttf-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/vandeventer/Documents/Pieter/pygame.resies.py", line 151, in <module>
        begin()
      File "/home/vandeventer/Documents/Pieter/pygame.resies.py", line 29, in begin
        message_display(over)
      File "/home/vandeventer/Documents/Pieter/pygame.resies.py", line 50, in message_display
        largeText = pygame.font.Font(None,75)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 74, in __getattr__
        raise NotImplementedError(MissingPygameModule)
    NotImplementedError: font module not available
    (ImportError: libSDL_ttf-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

this makes me think somethings wrong with the font i use, it is realy very frustrating, and i realy cant see anything wrong, here is my code:

```
    import pygame
    import time
    import random


    pygame.init()

    display_width = 1500
    display_height = 1000

    black = (255,255,255)
    white = (255,255,255)
    red = (255,0,0)
    back_ground = (25,25,25)
    over = "Start your engins!"



    car_width = 50

    gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("A bit Racey")
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    carImg = pygame.image.load("resieskar.png")
    resized = pygame.transform.scale(carImg, (50, 100))

    def begin():
        message_display(over)

    def you_win():
        message_display("You Win!")

    def things_dodged(count):
        font = pygame.font.SysFont(None,25)
        text = font.render("Dodged:  "+str(count),True,white)
        gameDisplay.blit(text, (0,0))

    def things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color):
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, block_color, [thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])

    def car(x,y):
        gameDisplay.blit(resized,(x,y))

    def text_objects(text, font):
        textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
        return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

    def message_display(text):
        largeText = pygame.font.Font(None,75)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
        pygame.display.update()

        time.sleep(2)
        game_loop()

    def crash():
        message_display('You Crashed!')



    def game_loop():
        global block_R
        global block_G
        global block_B
        global block_color

        black = (0,0,0)
        white = (255,255,255)
        red = (255,0,0)
        block_R = random.randrange(100,200)
        block_G = random.randrange(100,200)
        block_B = random.randrange(30,200)

        block_color = (block_R,block_G,block_B)

        x = (display_width*0.45)
        y = (display_height*0.8)
        x_change = 0

        thing_width = 100
        thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width-thing_width)
        thing_starty = -600
        thing_speed = 5
        thing_height = 100
        dodged = 0
        dificuilty = 2
        bigger = 15

        gameExit = False

        while not gameExit:

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()


                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                            x_change = 50

                    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                            x_change = -50

                if event.type == pygame. KEYUP:
                        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                            x_change = 0


                x += x_change



            gameDisplay.fill(back_ground)

            # things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color)
            things(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height, block_color)
            thing_starty += thing_speed
            car(x,y)
            things_dodged(dodged)
            if dodged > 34:
                you_win()

            if x > display_width - car_width or x < 0:
                crash()

            if thing_starty > display_height:
                thing_starty = 0 - thing_height
                thing_startx = random.randint(0,(795-int(thing_width)))
                dodged += 1
                bigger = bigger * 0.9
                dificuilty = dificuilty * 0.6
                thing_speed += dificuilty
                thing_width += bigger



            if y < thing_starty+thing_height:
                if x > thing_startx and x < thing_startx+thing_width or x+car_width > thing_startx and x+car_width<thing_startx+thing_width:
                    crash()


            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(60)

    begin()
    game_loop()
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
```

the only parts where i use the font is in message_display() and things_dodged()
id realy like any help, thanks

Comment: Remove this line: largeText = pygame.font.Font(None,75) and this line: font = pygame.font.SysFont(None,25)

Comment: It's looking for the font libSDL_ttf-2.0.so.0 and cant find it

Comment: ok, il try it thanks

Comment: it does not work, you cannot render it then or something, i dunno

Comment: what version of python are you using

Comment: i am using python3.4 however it cant be that couse it worked very fine until about a week ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was actuely very weird, today i decided to try and figure it out, and it worked perfectly fine, anyway, its fixed now

Answer (score 2):

Try to change `largeText = pygame.font.Font(None,75)` to `largeText = pygame.font.SysFont(None,75)`

Comment: it wont be any use trying, seeing that in things_dodged() i use .SysFont(),but thanks anyway i think i found the problem, ive resently upgraded to a newer version of linux, so thats probably the problem, il test it out tomorow and then remove the question if need be

Answer (score 0):

I want to add another way to resolve this issue without using `Sys.Font`.

If you want to use your own font, then you can download the font and provide the font path in pygame. Something like this:

```
OPEN_SANS = "assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf"

smallFont = pygame.font.Font(OPEN_SANS, 20)
mediumFont = pygame.font.Font(OPEN_SANS, 28)
largeFont = pygame.font.Font(OPEN_SANS, 40)
```